# Does $f''(0^+)=f''(0^-)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Consider the function, which is the join of two semicircles

$$ f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{1 - x^2} & x > 0 \\ 
1 & x = 0 \\
\sqrt{ 2 - (x-1)^2} & x < 0\end{array} \right.$$

Near $x = 0$, $f(x)$ is continuous and $f'(0)$ makes sense.  Does $f''(0^+)=f''(0^-)$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$f''(x) =
\begin{cases}
-(1-x^2)^{-3/2}      & x > 0 \\
0,                   & x = 0 \\
-2(2-(x-1)^2)^{-3/2} & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

So what are
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^-} f''(x) \text{ and } \lim_{x \to 0^+} f''(x)?
$$

Comment: Why does the formula above allow $x=0$ and how do you arrive at $f''(0)=0$?

Comment: @Roland you differentiate all 3 branches independently and two derivatives of the constant zero function yield the zero function.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'd do for an interval, but this doesn't work for single points: Define the function $f(x)= e^x, x\neq 1$ and $f(1)=e$. Would this function fulfil $f'(1)=0$?

Comment: @Roland yes, i would argue that it would indeed have $f'(1)=0$ and this is the main difference between your function and $g(x) = e^x$.

Comment: No, this view is faulty. $f'(x_0)$ is always defined as the differential quotient at the point $x_0$, which involves checking if the left and right limit exist and coincide.

Comment: @Roland do you want to bring a source for that? no sure this either correct or universally accepted